# Convince a manager to use newer compiler version

Tags: compiler, upgrade

I'm working in some environment where an older version of g++ is used to compile some production code: g++ 4.3.x . This might sound outrageous to you, but in various organizational settings prioritizing stability - it is acceptable; particularly seeing how the code being compiled is C++03...

Now, I want to convince my manager to switch to a newer compiler. The standards compliance argument is too weak, i.e. there are no significant changes expected in that codebase for now. I was thinking more of a performance and perhaps a correctness / bug fixing angle.

How would you suggest I make such an argument, and what kind of empirical data would I use to support it?

Additional details:

- The development environment is Linux machines with new(ish) CPUs but an old distribution.
- We do have cross-compilation, but to other x86_64 CPUs, so only partially.
- My manager trusts me as a person but this kind of trust is not nearly enough to push for such a decision.

Comment: [Is empirical evidence off topic here?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7573/31260)

Comment: @gnat: See edit. No longer asking for the actual empirical evidence.

Comment: What is your development environment (Linux? Windows)? Is it a cross-compiler? What build software do you use? Do your manager trust you?

Comment: I was expecting Israel defense economy to be more agile :-) but I am working close to the French defense economy

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I don't work for the Israeli defense/military/war establishment, on principle. I may be Israeli but I don't support the regime here.

Comment: You do work for what is called in France the military-techno-industrial complex of your country, and so do I. Otherwise, you probably won't have such insane requirements (or your employer will crash soon)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Look, I just don't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102579/discussion-between-basile-starynkevitch-and-einpoklum).

Comment: In what industry do you develop software? Who is the client?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: In the medical field.

Comment: Embedded medical devices? Then you absolutely should follow relevant industrial standards, in particular for safety-critical devices. E.g. The French [Carmat](https://www.carmatsa.com/) company is considering using  [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/). I do work close to Frama-C, but I forgot the relevant medical standards, even if I know about them (But I still qualify that company as part of French military-techno-industrial complex, since their major client could be the French army)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: No, it's not embedded, it's for processing medical data.

Comment: I mentioned https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_62304 but from what you explain it is not relevant in your case. However, not using recent GCC technology but ancient one is IMHO a symptom of very bad management. Consider looking for a better job (I would view GCC 4.3 as a red flag, telling me "run away")

Answer (score 2):

> Now, I want to convince my manager to switch to a newer compiler. The standards compliance argument is too weak, i.e. there are no significant changes expected in that codebase for now. I was thinking more of a performance and perhaps a correctness / bug fixing angle.

I see an important argument: GCC 4.3 is no more supported by the FSF. This is shown on the [GCC webpage](https://gcc.gnu.org/). The supported versions in end of 2019 are [GCC 8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/) and [GCC 9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/). Your employer could buy costly support of older GCC from companies like [AdaCore](https://www.adacore.com/) (typical yearly cost is the price of a car per seat).

And there is one thing to realize: GCC is indeed an old [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) project, but the GCC community is numerically important (at least a hundred people, most of them working at least half-time) and active. My intuition (but I did contribute to GCC, so I am biased) is that lots of clever people worked hard and together to improve GCC, so in general a recent GCC is "better" than older ones. You could ask your question [on `gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org`](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/) and/or look for reviews and benchmarks of GCC on [Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/) or [LWN](https://lwn.net/). Look also on the 
various changes to GCC, e.g. in [GCC 9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/changes.html), [GCC 8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/changes.html), [GCC 7](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/changes.html), [GCC 6](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/changes.html), [GCC 5](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html), [GCC 4.9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html), [GCC 4.8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html), [GCC-4.7](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html), [GCC-4.6](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html), [GCC-4.5](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/changes.html), [GCC-4.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/changes.html) etc... Notice that the numbering conventions changed in GCC 5.

Recent GCC did make progress on several aspects:

- better standard compliance with recent C++ standards (e.g. C++17)
- probably better cybersecurity aspects. Some security bugs might remain in unmaintained versions of GCC. See also [this](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-72/product_id-960/GNU-GCC.html).
- [GCC plugins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) support. IIRC, they did not exist in GCC 4.3; you could find interesting GCC plugins (such as [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/)), and you could develop -with permission from your manager- your own ones, specifically tuned for your software project (e.g. to check project-specific or industry-specific [coding rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_conventions)). Then look into the [GCC Resource Center](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/grc/).
- [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) did not exist in GCC 4.3; there are cases where it could be very handsome. But if on POSIX, you could consider generating C++ or C code on the fly then using `dlopen` (see [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c) as an example).
- better optimizations (even if that is really difficult to quantify), including a newer register allocator. My [Bismon draft report](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) gives examples, and you could consider link-time optimizations (so compiling and linking with `g++ -flto -O2`; with GCC 4.3 that was immature technology, today it is.)
- better compatibility between your C++03 code and external libraries written in C++11.
- improved [function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html), notably for [`visibility`](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility)
- better [pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pragmas.html)
- better handling of [precompiled headers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html) (when used correctly, they could accelerate build time).
- improved compile time.
- the [`-Og` flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) is nice with `gdb` but did not exist in 4.3
- probably better C++ standard library (more efficient, more standard conforming, less buggy) and better handling of template (and template expansion).
- better compliance with recent operating systems
- better support of debuggers (e.g. `gdb` printing C++ standard containers or strings instances, e.g. `std::map` or `std::string`s)
- **much better diagnostics and [warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)** (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra` gives much better warnings with GCC 9 than with GCC 4.3); several warnings did not exit in 4.3 (e.g. `-Wabi`, `-Weff++`).
- better [C++ specific options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html).
- better compile time detection of undefined behavior.

At least, ask permission to:

1) compile GCC 9 from its source code (this would take a whole day, or two, of your work time, and a few gigabytes of disk space)

2) build the company software you are working on using a good enough [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool. This should be perhaps as simple as `make CXX=g++-9-mine` if you are allowed to change your `$PATH`

BTW, if your software development is [safety-critical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety-critical_system) or [common criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Criteria) related, that should be stated in your question. In these cases, the rules may require you to use a specific compiler with specific options. But these rules apply to the deployed software, and you could still profit (with permission from your manager) of using a more recent GCC (e.g. because it gives better warnings).

You may be permitted to compile the C++ code with a new compiler, even if the deployed code has to be compiled with an old one (for example if it is a safety-critical software, e.g. [DO-178C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DO-178C) compliant or [IEC 62303](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_62304) compliant). Your employer could be interested in tools like [Frama-Clang](https://frama-c.com/frama-clang.html) or [Clang-static-analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) or the unmaintained [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/), but of course you should get permission to use them. If coding some parts in C, your employer could be interested in [CompCert](http://compcert.inria.fr/).

PS. I am professionally developing [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) and have developed [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/). My employer ([CEA LIST](http://www-list.cea.fr/en/)) would be very happy to sell support to yours (but I am not cheap; if you are serious about that, send me an email to `basile.starynkevitch@cea.fr` and I would read it in 2020).

Answer (score 0):

Presumably if technical arguments are lacking the reason you want the change is that you want the newer tech for your CV.

The argument then for your manager is the same. Recruitment is harder when you use old tech.

Comment: Ewan: They don't tell you what they recruit that you're stuck with these ancient systems. Plus, if you ask "Do you use C++14 or 11?" they can say "sure", because other systems are less outdated...

Answer (score 0):

It is a common misbelieve among software engineers that switching to a newer compiler will automatically and always be "better" - whatever that means. In fact, such decisions require a cost-/benefit analysis - and depending on the outcome, it might turn out that is better to stay with the old compiler - or not. You should be open to both potential outcomes, and try to make the analysis without any pre-judgement.

Switching to a newer compiler, first and foremost, will require some effort and produce costs. Moreover, it will also introduce a certain risk of introducing **new bugs**, especially when old code does not simply run out of the box, but has to be adapted manually to match changes in the C++ languages and libraries since GCC 4.3 (which were many!). So the first thing you have to make here is an estimation of how much effort it will require for the code base to switch to the newer compiler of your choice.

If the risk of introducing new bugs is acceptable (or not) depends heavily on the availability of a test suite with a high coverage. Do you have none? Then better invest some time to create one first, **before** you even think to switch to a different compiler.

For the estimation, I suggest you try to find a small, but representative module of the codebase which you can try to port and test on its own. This should give you a rough notion of how much effort the compiler update will require.

These efforts need to be balanced by the benefits you expect. The performance argument is usually very weak - if the software meets its performance requirements when compiled with GCC 4.3, switching to a newer compiler, even if the software will run several times faster, will simply be not necessary. And even if you have some "weak" performance requirements, where you hope a compiler change might bring you an improvement from the end users perspective, then you need to measure the specific use case, before and after the update, there is usually no other way you can get a reliable statement about the performance change.

On the other hand, benefits you will definitely get are

- the newer C++ language standards and libs, which improves the ways your team can add new features to the code base
- a compiler which presumably will work on newer operating system environments and hardware with a higher chance than the current one. I am not saying GCC 4.3 won't, but if it turns out it does not, and noone will fix this for you since it is not supported any more, you will either have to fix the problems with the compiler by yourself or make the compiler upgrade *then*, which might be significantly harder than doing it now.

So since you wrote *"no significant changes expected in that codebase"*,  you have to evaluate for your self what that **really** means. Do you expect no significant demands for new features as well as no demands for environmental updates? Then sticking with GCC 4.3 might be economically more sensible than changing the compiler. Or just "no new features", but maybe environmental changes? Then you have to evaluate if the benefits for making this possible will compensate the costs.